# How to remove route state from $stateProvider in angular UI router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

We're using angular UI router for our project. I have a requirement to generate route configuration dynamically. The project supports multiple applications. So for each application I must **delete** the existing configuration and generate a new configuration. So I need to know is there a way to delete the configured states dynamically